# Delegate directly or indirectly (by abstract method)?

Tags: java, collections, delegates

Is there an advantage to delegating directly or indirectly (by abstract method)?  (I made-up the terms "directly" and "indirectly"; I don't know if these are correct.)

Use Google Guava's [ForwardingList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) as an example.

Google chose to implement delegation indirectly, via an abstract method.

```
public abstract class ForwardingList<T>
extends List<T> {

    protected ForwardingList() { }

    protected abstract List<T> delegate();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate().size();
    }

}
```

Alternatively, this class could be implemented by accepting a `List` as a constructor argument.

```
public abstract class ForwardingList<T>
extends List<T> {

    private final List<T> list;

    protected ForwardingList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

Again: Is there an advantage of one over the other?  If possible, please provide a simple use case to prefer direct or indirect delegation.

Comment: Seems like an example of [Double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "indirect delegation" is more general / less restrictive than "direct delegation". Lets say you are writing class A which extends the ForwardingList. If you use the direct delegation, then you need to pass the instance of the list to the constructor of A. Now if the construction of the underlying list is very expensive operation and the call to A.size() is not always executed by the users of A you might want to initialize the underlying list lazily to improve performance. That is when the "indirect delegation" becomes useful.